# Diferencia entre sitio y asedio

Tags: diferencias-entre-palabras

No consigo cuál es la diferencia entre asedio y sitio, si es que existe. Generalmente, existe algún matiz o una palabra que es más técnica que otra. ¿Por qué se llama el sitio de París y el asedio de Boston? Supongo que la diferencia está en los detalles militares. ¿Cómo podría confirmar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La única diferencia que registra el DLE entre *[sitiar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Y2XMutI)* y *[asediar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3wfXz4F)* es que este último tiene un significado extra: "presionar insistentemente a alguien".

A mí, aun sin ser consciente de esta distinción, siempre me pareció que **sitiar** una fortaleza o ciudad tenía connotaciones de inmovilidad (montar un cerco alrededor del lugar y esperar a que se rinda), mientras que **asediar** implicaba movimiento, es decir, cercar pero también hostigar, atacar activamente las murallas o lo que fuera.

Más allá de esta distinción, es posible que se diga "el sitio de París" y "el asedio de Boston" por simple repetición de la forma en que se hizo conocido el evento la primera vez. En otros casos se usa indistintamente una u otra palabra, aunque *sitio* parece ser más común.

[image]

Comment: Sitio probablemente es más común porque es sinónimo de lugar o de servidor web.

Comment: @Mauricio - No creo que eso sea factor.